# 100+ Targets for one Xcode Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, target, targets

I am wondering if anyone has experience with having 100+ targets in a single xcode project. I have a case right now where we are building many apps that use the same code base. There is some debate internally that if the amount of apps gets to an unmanageable level aka (Maybe a couple of 1000 apps) we are going to have issues.

So my Question: Does anyone have experience with making a xcode project that has a ton of apps/targets (100+) in one project? Is there any issues with this? Is it easier then having a single project for each one and just sharing code with symbolic links?

I have built a project and made about 80 targets. Besides xcode crashing a couple of times while I was creating them (I think this was because I was using hot-keys and going really fast) it seemed like it was fine. I did not see any major performance hits, but since this was not a full project I am skeptical that this was tested fully.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

So I found some information hidden in a post of a site called openradar. I think it will answer my question. I would love to hear from some real world experience through. So if anyone still has input please add it. I will be doing some more research on the subject.

Link to Post: http://openradar.io/15060709

Also I asked apple for comment on this as well and as soon as I get a response back I will post it in this answer.